# How to assign values within mongodb findOne method to global variable in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
var user_poster = {}   
db.carts.findOne(q, function(err, user_cart) {
    if (err) return   
    next(err);
    if(!user_cart) {
        return res.send({"error": "art not found"});
    }
    cart_for_user(user_cart);
})
function cart_for_user(name) {global.user_poster = [name];}
console.log(user_poster);
```

I need to assign mongoDB response date to global variable.

Comment: R u getting any error by running the above code??

Comment: Nope.. user_poster value will be null

Comment: Did you gone through the post suggested by chridam..

Comment: Yes but its no use